# How to build a Docker image with a specific version of a dependency in requirements.txt?

Tags: python, docker

I'm building a Docker image to run a deep learning model in Google cloud. I'm using tensorflow as one of the dependencies and specify it in `requirements.txt`. I didn't figure out how to specify the dependency version and the image was built with tensorflow 2.0.

When testing various implementations of the model I've faced problems when the code was written for the older versions of tensorflow. Finally I made it work after some refactoring.

What is the right way to add a specific version of a dependency to `requirements.txt`? For example, I need `tensorflow` [1.14](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/tree/r1.14/site/en/api_docs).

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.6
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt
COPY app.py /app
CMD ["python", "app.py"]~
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
keras
tensorflow
flask
gevent
pillow
requests
```

Comment: [this might help you](https://intellipaat.com/community/31672/how-to-use-requirements-txt-to-install-all-dependencies-in-a-python-project) i believe you just need to specify the version on the requirements txt.

Answer (score 3):

you can specify a version in the requirements.txt file.. like

```
tensorflow==1.14
```

also see: https://pip.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/requirements.html

Answer (score 1):

As @Bastian said you can specify a version with `tensorflow==1.14`

Furthermore you can create that list from your local development environment with this command:

```
python3 -m pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

`python3` may vary. It can be `python`, `py` or `py3`.

Locking all your python modules to a version is a good idea. Also ensure you are using the same Python version across all environments. You can check your used Python version with `python3 -V`